# UI5 Odata batch update - Connect return messages to single operation

Tags: abap

I perform a batch update on an OData v2 model, that contains several operations.
The update is performed in a single changeset, so that a single failed operation fails the whole update.

If one operation fails (due to business logic) and a message returns. Is there a way to know which operation triggered the message? The response I get contains the message text and nothing else that seems useful.

The error function is triggered for every failed operation, and contains the same message every time.

Maybe there is a specific way the message should be issued on the SAP backend?
The ABAP method /iwbep/if_message_container->ADD_MESSAGE has a parameter IV_KEY_TAB, but it does not seem to affect anything.

**Edit:**
Clarification following conversation.
My service does not return a list of messages, it performs updates. If one of the update operations fails with a message, I want to connect the message to the specific update that failed, preferably without modifying the message text.
An example of the error response I'm getting:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"SY/530",
      "message":{
         "lang":"en",
         "value":"<My message text>"
      },
      "innererror":{
         "application":{
            "component_id":"",
            "service_namespace":"/SAP/",
            "service_id":"<My service>",
            "service_version":"0001"
         },
         "transactionid":"",
         "timestamp":"20181231084555.1576790",
         "Error_Resolution":{
            // Sap standard message here
         },
         "errordetails":[
            {
               "code":"<My message class>",
               "message":"<My message text>",
               "propertyref":"",
               "severity":"error",
               "target":""
            },
            {
               "code":"/IWBEP/CX_MGW_BUSI_EXCEPTION",
               "message":"An exception was raised.",
               "propertyref":"",
               "severity":"error",
               "target":""
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same exact message for all operations the simplest way to be able to determine the message origin would be to add a specific 'tag' to it in the backend.

For example, you can fill the PARAMETER field of the message structure with a specific value for each operation. This way you can easily determine the origin in gateway or frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, my idea was to have arbitrary messages from SAP backend, and tie them to a specific operation from the batch. I hoped to achieve this without modifying the message text.

Comment: My proposal wasn't to modify the message text but rather to fill an **unused field** in the `BAPIRET2` (message) structure in the backend, to be able to determine its origin.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. The only thing that is passed to the odata is the message text.

Comment: So you just return a string containing a message text? Can you post an example of the OData response?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try the following.

override the following DPC methods:

- changeset_begin: set cv_defer_mode to abap_true
- changeset_end: just redefine it, with nothing inside
- changeset_process:

here you get a list of your requests in a table, which has the operation number (thats what you seek), and the key value structure (iwbep.blablabla) for the call. 
loop over the table, and call the method for each of the entries.

put the result of each of the operations in the CT_CHANGESET_RESPONSE.

in case of one operation failing, you can raise the busi_exception in there and there you can access the actual operation number.

for further information about batch processing you can check out this link:
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/06/batch-request-in-sap-gateway/

is that what you meant?